# How to deal with {AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401} axios/react/typescript ?Bearer token

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

Problem is that I have bearer token for API but for some reason my identification doesn't work:

> {bearer token :wm3gg940gy0xek1ld98uaizhz83c6rh2sir9f9fu}

```
   import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from "react";
   import axios from "axios";
   import { IUser } from "../types/Types";
   import List from "./List";
   import UserItem from "./UserItem";
   const HomePage: FC = () => {
   const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUser[]>([]);
 
   useEffect(() => {
   fetchUsers();
   }, []);
    async function fetchUsers() {
     try {
       const response = await axios.get<IUser[]>(
       "https://api.json-generator.com/templates/ZM1r0eic3XEy/data",
        {
       method: "post",
      headers:new Headers({ Authorization:'Bearer 
     'wm3gg940gy0xek1ld98uaizhz83c6rh2sir9f9fu
 '})
        }
      );
     setUsers(response.data);
      } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
        }
       }
      return (
        <List
        items={users}
        renderItem={(user) => <UserItem user={user} key={user.id} />}
         />
        );
     };

     export default HomePage;
```

Comment: `metod` should be `method` - also, not sure about `headers:new Headers` ... usually you just pass an Object to headers property (haven't used axios in years though) - and `'Bearer' 'wm3gg940gy0xek1ld98uaizhz83c6rh2sir9f9fu'` looks like a syntax error, so your code wouldn't even run

Comment: 'metod' was syntax error that i accidentally wrote on stackoverflow in VScode it was method AND "'Bearer' 'wm3gg940gy0xek1ld98uaizhz83c6rh2sir9f9fu' looks like a syntax error, so your code wouldn't even run" I tried multiple combinations and either don't worked

Comment: did you try `headers: { Authorization:"Bearer wm3gg940gy0xek1ld98uaizhz83c6rh2sir9f9fu"}`

Comment: Oh thanks it actually worked  wasted 6 hours figuring out this